# Report designed with Jaspersoft Studio shows blank content on the report server

Tags: jasper-reports

We are using the free community editions of JasperSoft Studio 6.6.0. And after designing and viewing my report locally I deployed it to our JasperSoft server. When I run it on the server with the same parameters I get a blank page output.

I checked the catalina.out log where our JasperSoft server is running and there are no errors when running the report.

Are there any required values that I forgot to include in my jrxml file? I assume JasperSoft Studio fills in some missing settings when running locally on my computer but the server doesn't bother to give any warnings, it just puts out a blank page.

This is the jrxml content (long xml text follows):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="WSRDRGL" columnCount="3" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="190" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ece08145-f065-4f17-841f-2b1537201893">
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="BANNER_TEST"/>
 <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="https://localserver.com:8443/reports/"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/Reports/main_jrxml"/>
 <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/Reports/WSRDRGL_TEST"/>
 <parameter name="PONEUP" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <parameter name="USERNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <queryString language="plsql">
  <![CDATA[{call WSRDRGL_HANDLER($P{PONEUP},$P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR})}]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="SPRIDEN_ID" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SPRIDEN_ID"/>
 </field>
 <field name="SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME"/>
 </field>
 <field name="SPRIDEN_MI" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SPRIDEN_MI"/>
 </field>
 <field name="SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME"/>
 </field>
 <field name="full_name" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="full_name"/>
 </field>
 <field name="street" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="street"/>
 </field>
 <field name="city" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="city"/>
 </field>
 <field name="SPRADDR_ZIP" class="java.lang.String">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SPRADDR_ZIP"/>
 </field>
 <field name="SPRADDR_PIDM" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SPRADDR_PIDM"/>
 </field>
 <background>
  <band splitType="Stretch"/>
 </background>
 <detail>
  <band height="78" splitType="Stretch">
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="-2" y="12" width="100" height="12" uuid="28f8ca92-d2e6-412a-b3f4-837eca23ced2"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{full_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="-2" y="25" width="100" height="12" uuid="d2037bf2-f6d7-4910-9d38-63fc8669ea38"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{street}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="-2" y="38" width="100" height="12" uuid="9def2228-d0d7-4f22-a505-f8fc38747228"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
   <textField>
    <reportElement x="-2" y="51" width="100" height="12" uuid="e5dd0604-cf29-4b3f-a824-59df87b57c92"/>
    <textElement>
     <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="8"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SPRADDR_ZIP}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
  </band>
 </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

NOTE: The report prints labels using horizontal printOrder and columnCount of 3.
The fields are as generic as they can be.

Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After rebuilding the report it worked. Before I had deleted the sections that I didn't need (Title, Page Header, Page Footer, Summary). For the new report I just left those with their minimal height in JasperSoft Studio properties.

When I compare both jrxml files these are the misssing lines from the old report:

```
<title>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnHeader>

( Report Details ... )

<pageFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
```